# changing column names within a function so it doesn't get overwritten

Tags: r

I am trying to make a function that creates new columns for k in 0:5. While doing so, I want the name of the column to change based on the value of k, so it's not just writing the data over the same column. A very stripped down idea of what I want to do is below: Where the value I am trying to add into a new column changes by k (successfully), but I don't know how to tell the df$columnname on the left to update based on the value of k.

```
k = 1L
for(k in 0:5){
  df$value_k <- paste0((df$IV1*k),"_",df$TIME)
}

dput(df)
structure(list(TIME = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), IV1 = c(29, 33, 40, 44, 75, 
79, 30, 34, 20, 24, 45, 49, 69, 73, 33, 37, 40, 44, 29, 33, 76, 
80, 61, 65)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

what I want at the end of the function is a dataframe with six additional rows named value_0 through value_5; with the appropriate information from the right side of the code (paste0...etc). How can I edit the function to include columns that change name by iteration?

Comment: Use `[[` instead of `$` and pass the column name as string for the function

Comment: If you are rbinding rows to the data, the column type will change.  Right now, they are numeric columns, when you add string, it changes to 'character' class.   Also, `paste` is vectorized. The value_k` would be `df[[paste0('value_', k)]]`

Comment: @akrun, that solves it. Sorry for the confusion - meant columns. Edited to reflect that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @akron's comments, here is the solution, with outcome below:

```
k = 1L
for(k in 0:5){
  df[[paste0('value_', k)]] <- paste0((df$IV1*k),"_",df$TIME)
}

head(df, n=32)
   TIME IV1 value_0 value_1 value_2 value_3 value_4 value_5
1     1  29     0_1    29_1    58_1    87_1   116_1   145_1
2     2  33     0_2    33_2    66_2    99_2   132_2   165_2
3     1  40     0_1    40_1    80_1   120_1   160_1   200_1
```